# Swift - EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

I am trying to remove audio from video file. I am getting this error only in **Simulator (iPadPro-12.9 inch)**. I ran this code in all other devices in simulator. It worked perfectly.

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

in

> let exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset:
>   composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!

this line.

this is my code

```
func removeAudioFromVideo(_ videoURL: URL) {
        let inputVideoURL: URL = videoURL
        let sourceAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputVideoURL)
        let sourceVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack? = sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
        let composition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var compositionVideoTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack? = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
        let x: CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, sourceAsset.duration)
        _ = try? compositionVideoTrack!.insertTimeRange(x, of: sourceVideoTrack!, at: kCMTimeZero)

        mutableVideoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/mutableVideo\(mutableVideoCounter).mp4")
        mutableVideoCounter += 1

        //video orientation
        let assetVideoTrack = (sourceAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)).last
        compositionVideoTrack = (composition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)).last
        if ((assetVideoTrack?.isPlayable)! && (compositionVideoTrack?.isPlayable)!) {
            compositionVideoTrack?.preferredTransform = (assetVideoTrack?.preferredTransform)!
        }

        let exporter: AVAssetExportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter.outputURL = mutableVideoURL as URL
        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler:
            {
                switch exporter.status
                {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed:
                    print("failed \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.cancelled:
                    print("cancelled \(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.unknown:
                    print("unknown\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.waiting:
                    print("waiting\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatus.exporting:
                    print("exporting\(String(describing: exporter.error))")
                default:
                    print("-----Mutable video exportation complete.\(self.mutableVideoURL)")                    
                }
        })
    }
```

screen shot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is a composition there? it looks like it i s nil and try to not just put "!" make some guard or check in different way if it is not a nil;

Comment: Additionally to the correct comment from Lu_ : use exportPresets before creating the ExportSession to find out, if composition is compatible.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetexportsession/1390567-exportpresets

Comment: but this worked perfectly in all other devices. Any reason ?

Comment: Did you try it and did it help?

Comment: if you use simulator of iOS 13 or above, it crashes but it works on devices, and try simulator iPhone 5s (iOS 11). I try to learn it from [raywenderlich.com tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) and it crashes on simulator - iPhone 11 (iOS 13) but works on simulator iPhone 5s (iOS 11) and my device - iPhone 6 (iOS 12.5)